# How can I make a file trully immutable (non-deletable and read-only)?

Tags: windows, security, delphi, winapi

I need to make a file truly read only - to keep it as is. No delete, no nothing.

(Setting the *'ReadOnly'* attribute isn't an option)

I see now some approaches:

1. Use a program to keep the file open. Drawback: One can kill the process an then the file closes.
2. Use a program to set the security attributes. Drawback: The file can be deleted. Also, the attributes can be changed back.

Any ideas? Also, a sample code (preferably in Delphi) would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to all answers so far. They are really great. I realize that I wasn't very clear. The problem which we want to solve is this:

There are some .txt-like files which contains sensitive information. Our clients wants to be sure that these files aren't changed 'behind the scenes' on their computers. We should mention that their PCs can be infected easily with malware specifically targeted to do this thing. Our clients should be able to open these files with Notepad, Wordpad etc. but they accept that the files are Read Only. If any of our clients take a decisive action like entering in 'Safe Mode' etc. and tampering the files from there is their responsibility. We should guard them from *any* malware, including a zero-day attack. (Hence a classical Antivirus solution isn't so appropriate).

Can you give now some ideas?

*PS: My most sincere apologies once again for not being so clear from the beginning.*

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but you can always find "drawbacks". If you burn it into a ROM, someone might attack it with a hammer and destroy it physically. If you engrave it into a huge marble rock with a robotic arm, time and weather will destroy it in a few million years. As an engineer, you have to balance pros and cons. In this case, the ideal balance would be protecting it with filesystem permissions in my opinion.

Comment: There isn't possible without some kind of read-only media like a CD-ROM.  Even then malware could modify the kernel to return different information when those files are requested so that the files would seem different to that computer.

Comment: WRT the edit, that makes more sense, but providing a reasonable explanation for why you want to do something impossible doesn't make it possible.  In this specific case, I'd try encrypting the files in question and adding a checksum to make sure malware isn't tampering with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way be to sure that these files aren't changed 'behind the scenes' would be to add a signature to the file.

To sign the file you could for example:
Make a string with the whole content of the file + a secret password and calculate an SHA1-Hash of the string. Then add this hash on the first or last line of the file.

To check the signature:
Read the file, remove the line with the hash, add the secret password, recalculte the hash and check if it is the same as the one in the file.

To calculate SHA-1-Hashes with Delphi you can for example use [MessageDigests](http://www.ohdave.com/delphi/).

Comment: +1 Yes, hashing is a good idea. You could even sign it with a PGP/GPG key if you're really paranoid.

Comment: This is the way I think - if you can change info on drive, malware can change it too. For people who think that ROM is the top of security: file system calls can be hooked and malware can replace files on fly. So, this answer is most useful here, take +1.

Comment: (P.S. don't use SHA-1 as it's old nowadays, use newer/stronger algorithms)

Answer (score 17):

This is one of the "what would happen if that were true?" questions. It has nothing to do with the operating system, the points apply equally to any general purpose computer.

Imagine that there were a way to somehow create an immutable file.

- What's there to stop someone from filling up a file system with an immutable file (or many of them)?
- What if someone were to create immutable files with pathnames the operating system needs (Windows example - NTUSER.DAT for some user, *nix example - /bin/ls, etc.)?
- What if the operating system decides it must move the file (e.g., while defragmenting or otherwise reorganizing the file system)?
- What if a piece of malware replaces a system file with a copy of itself then makes that file immutable to prevent anyone from ever cleaning the system?

I feel the question is incomplete as it is now. Could you edit it to include more details about the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: +1. It has nothing to do either with Delphi or the Windows API, and with security only as in "a false sense of".

Answer (score 16):

You can't do that, for the simple reason that you shouldn't ever be allowed to anyway.  As Mihal pointed out, this has the potential to wreak havoc on a computer.

Programming Ethics 101:  If your program is going to run on someone else's computer, remember that it's their property, not yours.  That means they have the right to modify and/or delete anything they want to.  Try to treat the system like your property, and they'll treat your program like malware.

Probably the best solution, if you need to make certain that a file will be available, is Massif's idea to embed it within your program as a resource.  That way, nothing short of someone tampering with the EXE will stop you from having it available, and if that *does* happen, you've got bigger problems to worry about anyway.

Comment: "Try to treat the system like your property, and they'll treat your program like malware."  
Excellent one!

Comment: Glad you like it.  I just wish more coders would take it to heart.

Comment: Ironic that it makes virus scanners rather much like malware.

Answer (score 13):

burn a cd.

Comment: There it is! Like the PROM answer, put the file on a write-once media. That’s the only way. If you put it on any sort of re-writable media, it will *never* be immutable; not even if the drive is damaged.

Comment: Upvoted. This is a pretty cool idea. Thinking out of the box. Impressed!

Answer (score 6):

Buy a PROM, and a micro controller programmer kit, and burn your file into the ROM...

Comment: ... or buy EEPROM if you want to change the file later

Answer (score 4):

you're doomed. Even windows can't prevent me deleting files arbitrarily if I boot into safe mode.

How about setting a watcher on the file in question and replacing it with a pristine one should it be changed? Or embedding the file in the resources of the program that needs it?

Answer (score 3):

Burn it to write-once media.

Answer (score 3):

Raymond Chen from Microsoft just recently wrote an article that's closely related: [The way to stop people from copying files to a folder is to use NTFS security, not to block drag/drop](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090826-00/?p=16973). While this one mentions trying to stop someone from copying a file to a specific folder you can use the same solution presented to fix your problem here.

To properly secure the file and prevent tampering you can set the ACLs on the file to have Read permissions but deny Write, Delete and Change permissions. You can set that for a specific user, group, or even everyone! The owner of the file will *always* have permission to change the permissions, so you can't permanently lock yourself out (even if you try to deny the `CREATOR OWNER` special object). Keep in mind that to manually set these from the security dialog box, you'll have to enter the advanced permissions area, they aren't available from the standard page. You may also want to break inheritance so that the file has only the permissions you set and none from its parent.

In this case it would be best to leverage options that are already there and so you won't have to try and hack the system to make work. NTFS has robust security and can accomplish what you want without you writing code. You can also work with the security directly through the WINAPI using methods related to [File Security and Access Rights (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364399(VS.85).aspx). You can provide the permissions when you call the first `CreateFile` or change permissions after the fact by using [SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379579(VS.85).aspx) or [SetSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379588(VS.85).aspx).

**EDIT:** To address the concerns of malware, you can even deny `SYSTEM` access so even services running under the system account cannot delete it or write to it. I've actually taken care of one pesky virus in that method. it would keep creating a directory, so I booted PE, emptied out the directory, then denied everyone access to it including the `SYSTEM` account. The virus was unable to propagate while I worked on removing it.

Comment: Some malware can bypass WinAPI and get raw read-write access to hard drive. Then they can change the file by rewriting it without WinAPI...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want this? It seams to me like an odd requirement.

I don't think you can do this. The best alikes I can think of are:
Create the file as an admin and set the permissions that so that a normal user change not change it (this assumes different users) or create an application that resets the file if it changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use windows [security acls](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1050976.html) to protect the file. However if the person has access to the hardware then they can always as massif says boot into another mode or os and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just encrypt the file and open/close it along with your executable? Or place it in your self-made filesystem?